# How to findout that bluetooth is on or off Outside CBCentralManagerDelegate. (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

In my app when I launch my app I want to check that device Bluetooth is on or off.
generally, we can get this in CBCentralManagerDelegate. Here is my Code

```
     var manager:CBCentralManager!

 in init() or viewDidLoad()
 {
     manager = CBCentralManager()
     manager.delegate = self
 }

// Delegate method

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {

  if central.state == .poweredOn {

  }
  else if central.state == .resetting{

  }
  else if central.state == .unauthorized
  {

  }
  else if central.state == .unknown
  {

   }
  else if central.state == .unsupported
  {

  }
  else if central.state == .poweredOff{

     print("Bluetooth is not Connected.Please Enable it")
  }
}
```

But the issue is that in this method we can get Bluetooth state only when the state is updated during app life cycle.
But we can not check at launch time without any state change.
So how can I get this at launch time to check that Bluetooth is on or off?

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after you instantiate a `CBCentralManager` you will get a call to the `centralManagerDidUpdateState` delegate method with the current state. An explicit change in Bluetooth state is not required to trigger this behaviour.

I would suggest that you use appropriate `CBCentralManager` initialiser so that you can specify your delegate as part of the initialisation:

```
manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
```

This is the only way to obtain Bluetooth power state.

There is no synchronous method that reports the current Bluetooth power state.

You need to update your UI/display an alert or take whatever other action you require in response to the delegate method call.

You can specify an [option](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanageroptionshowpoweralertkey) when you instantiate your `CBCentralManager` that causes iOS to show a system alert if Bluetooth is not currently on.

```
manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options:
            [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey:1])
```